# Unable to make Arduino IDE recognize Adafruit BLE Feather M0

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I have an Adafruit BLE Feather M0. I am following these instructions here - https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-express-designed-for-circuit-python-circuitpython?view=all

Really hoping someone can help me out as I am stuck in the very first task it self.

I see the board and select the correct one "Adafruit Feather M0" but the Port doesn't show serial options. It only shows the "/dev/cu.Bluetooth-incoming-Port" as an option. The instructions above show serial ports to choose from. What am I missing? This seems too basic to not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cable I was using only supports charging and not data. TIL!

The other main thing, I think this is what hit me is that Arduino and Circuitpython are not enabled at the same time. If you install Cirtuitpython it will disable Arduino.